# Как идентифицировать ПК из общей сети на сайте?

Tags: php, html, http

Всем привет. Интересует уточнение по поводу посещения сайта с нескольких ПК объединенных в сеть. Как я понимаю, если есть локальная сеть состоящая из нескольких ПК и все они имеют выход в интернет, то на сайте идентифицирует один IP адрес для всех ПК сети? В таком случае, можно ли как то идентифицировать каждый отдельный ПК в общей сети на сайте(кроме куков)?

Comment: [Способы идентификации в интернете](http://javascript.ru/unsorted/id)